# Postqresql slow query runtime

Tags: sql, postgresql

i am an intern who is tasked to optimize a database code that can take up to ~6 second to finish executing under load.

so far, what i had done is to cache the query in a materialized table which lowered the time from 0.223ms to 0.029ms if i were to execute the query in the database itself

however, it did not lower the timing on the local backend when testing the query itself.

i tried many testings to see what was going on and realized that the timing when executing the query itself takes about 80ms, but the result returned in 0.029ms.
[notice the green box with query runtime and the actual time of the query planner][1]

this reflects correctly on my docker where i did a console.time and console.timeEnd on the line of code. It also took very high amount of time to execute.
[in this case, the query execution took up to 200ms][2]

the actual query itself is:
SELECT * FROM materalized_view WHERE id = '...'

and the plan result is:

```
"Index Scan using id_index on mat_view_table  (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=834) (actual time=0.028..0.033 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  Index Cond: (id_index = '...'::uuid)"
"  Buffers: shared hit=3"
"Planning Time: 0.113 ms"
"Execution Time: 0.065 ms"
```

any help or advice would be suggested! thank you
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Gl7L.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VboZg.png

Comment: When the query execution takes less than a millisecond, but it takes 80 milliseconds for the client to receive the result, it must be something in between. Check your network first.

Comment: @FrankHeikens i did tried that initially, but our company's internet speed is quite fast. I'm unable to ping the server itself as i think the sys admin disabled incoming pings.

Comment: Show your results to the sysadmin, these results show them the results of a fast query and something else that must be slow. We don't have access to your system, hard to help

Comment: @FrankHeikens haha, i tried to do that as well too. He is my supervisor, and he told me it may be row lock? So i'm currently researching about it and im stucked, so i came to stackoverflow to ask questions haha

Comment: @FrankHeikens maybe there is something that is blocked in the middle like you said? Are there any suggestions so that I can bring this up to them? Thanks!

Comment: If it was a rowlock, you could have seen that. But a rowlock for a SELECT, readers are almost never blocked by anything. How do you update your mat views? (and why do you use mat views in the first place?)

Comment: @FrankHeikens we update the mat views by listening to any trigger actions like UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT, on a specific table. As these records are used to determine what are the configurations of some applications that we are making, it wont be updated so much.

As for why I used a materialized view, is that we currently have 2 joins and it takes about 0.300ms ~ to finish executing one query. So researched and decided to go with a materalized view as its stored directly in the RAM and it did improve query performance by A TON! (0.300ms to 0.017ms)

Comment: Well, that rules out the row lock.

Comment: A change from 0.300ms to 0.017ms doesn't justify the use of a materialized view in my opinion. The only reason why a fast query needs to be even faster, would be if you run that statements hundreds (or even thousands) of times per second

Comment: 80ms is about the fastest pgAdmin4 ever manages to do anything.  The only problem this indicates is that you have chosen to use pgAdmin4.  The 2nd image might show something more worthy of investigation, but I have no idea what that is from or what it is showing.  Looks like some kind of app-server log?

Comment: @jjanes Hi, yeah it is a app-server log where it sends a query to the database and a console.Time is there to check how long it took to retrieve the data. Sometimes it is 30ms, but it can also spike up to 500ms randomly.

Comment: Set up auto_explain to record the equivalent of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for slow queries.  Then you can see if the occasional slowness is happening on the PostgreSQL side, or just on the client side.

Comment: @jjanes hi, yes its on the postgresql side as it takes ~50ms to execute the query. Anyway to fix it?

Comment: Not without seeing the output....